# Filter rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
name        date_one        date_two
-----------------------------------------
sue
sue
john    
john        13-06-2019
sally       23-04-2019
sally       23-04-2019      25-04-2019
bob         18-05-2019      14-06-2019
bob         18-05-2019      17-06-2019
```

The data contains duplicate `name` rows. I need to filter the data based on the following (in this order of priority):

1. For each `name`, keep the row with the newest `date_two`. If the `name` doesn't have any rows which have values for `date_two`, go to step 2
2. For each `name`, keep the row with the newest `date_one`. If the `name` doesn't have any rows which have values for `date_one`, go to step 3
3. These `names` don't have any rows which have a `date_one` or `date_two` so just keep the first row for that `name`

The above dataframe would be filtered to:

```
name        date_one        date_two
-----------------------------------------
sue
john        13-06-2019
sally       23-04-2019      25-04-2019
bob         18-05-2019      17-06-2019
```

This doesn't need to be done in the most performant way. The dataframe is only a few thousand rows and only needs to be done once. If it needs to be done in multiple (slow) steps that's fine.

Comment: hmmm, there are also multiple columns in data? Or all values are same in `date_one` per groups, no another columns, so aggregation by max working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) per groups for rows by maximal values, then filter out already matched values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and last join together value by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df['date_one'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_one'], dayfirst=True)
df['date_two'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_two'], dayfirst=True)

#rule1
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('name')['date_two'].idxmax().dropna()]

#rule2
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('name')['date_one'].idxmax().dropna()]
df2 = df2[~df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]

#rule3
df3 = df[~df['name'].isin(df1['name'].append(df2['name']))].drop_duplicates('name')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).sort_index()
print (df)
    name   date_one   date_two
0    sue        NaT        NaT
3   john 2019-06-13        NaT
5  sally 2019-04-23 2019-04-25
7    bob 2019-05-18 2019-06-17
```